# improving home grown closed captioning

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

this may get closed as request for software, or opinion based but I'm hopeful it might not.

I wrote a JS web page for our church that uses speech recognition to transcribe the pastor's speech and display it as closed captions on a monitor. The accuracy is around 90%. I was wondering if anyone had suggestions to improve it or if using an API like Google Translate would help.

you can try it here.  https://bryandellinger.github.io/voicetotext/
here it is in github

**warning this version has a large list of profanities in it**
https://github.com/bryandellinger/voicetotext/blob/main/index.html
below is the relevant code.

```
  const badWords = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'grape', 'pear']
    window.SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition || window.SpeechRecognition;
        let finalTranscript = '';
        let recognition = new window.SpeechRecognition();

        recognition.interimResults = true;
        recognition.maxAlternatives = 10;
        recognition.continuous = true;
        recognition.addEventListener('end', () => {
           recognition.start();
          });

        recognition.onresult = (event) => {
            let interimTranscript = '';
            for (let i = event.resultIndex, len = event.results.length; i < len; i++) {
                let transcript = (event.results[i][0].transcript);
                const words = transcript.split(" ");
                const words2 = [];
                words.forEach(element => {
                    if (element.indexOf('*') < 0){
                        words2.push(element);
                    }
                });
                const filteredWords = words2.filter(word  => !badWords.includes(word.toLowerCase()));
              
                if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
                    finalTranscript += filteredWords.join(' ');
                } else {
                    interimTranscript += filteredWords.join(' ');
                }
            }
            interimTranscript = interimTranscript.length > 1000 ? interimTranscript.substring(1000) :  interimTranscript;
            finalTranscript = finalTranscript.length > 1000 ? finalTranscript.substring(1000) :  finalTranscript;
            document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = finalTranscript + '<i style="color:#FFFFFF;">' + interimTranscript + '</>';
            const myDiv = document.getElementById('container');
            myDiv.scrollTop = myDiv.scrollHeight;
        }
        recognition.start();
```

Comment: Hi Bryan, a couple of comments here that might help us answer this question better. Firstly, have you compared this across browsers? Different browsers implement speech recognition differently. From memory, Chrome uses an async call back to a Google service, and Mozilla does it offline. Do you get different results in different browsers? Secondly, web speech recognition has no way of knowing the accent of the speaker, or the domain they're speaking about. Does the pastor have an accent, or use words that are specific to the sermon that are not frequently used in everyday speech?

Comment: @Kathy thank you for that, I did not know it was implemented differently per browsers I've been using chrome and its pretty good maybe 90%.  but I'll give the others a try.   the text is english and the pastor is a native Pennsylvanian but he does get excited and talk fairly quickly.  was just wondering if there was another thing I could run it through.  like google translate, or some kind of AI api that would check if the sentence was non sensical and make a best guess

Comment: Definitely check out Whisper - it's a new model from OpenAi - https://github.com/openai/whisper